# How to add Scala IDE *.sbt syntax highlighting support?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Eclipse with Scala IDE 4.7.1.
Is there a way to add the syntax highlighting for *.sbt file in Eclipse ?

Comment: Add sbt plugin to your eclipse ide from eclipse market store

Comment: It seems that there is no plugin for SBT on the [eclipse marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/sbt). Could you provide a link to an available plugin ?

Comment: I'm sorry! Itseems there is no eclipse plugin of sbt in market store.. U can use "sbt eclipse" plugin in sbt project then run "sbt eclipse" in sbt shell which generates .classpath for eclipse. Import the project in eclipse.